# Linear functions that cancels on $\nabla L^2(\Omega) d

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $\nabla :L^2_0(\Omega) \rightarrow H^{-1}(\Omega)$ be the gradient operator.$$L^2_0(\Omega)= \{ f \in L^2(\Omega); \int_{\Omega} f=0\}$$

I have read that the the dual of $\nabla (L^2(\Omega))$ which is the set of linear and continuous functions on $\nabla (L^2(\Omega))$ can be identified with the qoutient of $H^1_0(\Omega)$ by all the linear functionality’s which cancel on $\nabla (L^2(\Omega))$ that is the set:
$$Z=\{ f \in H^1_0(\Omega) ; div(f)=0 \} $$
My problem is why $Z$ takes this form? If any one can explain please.

Comment: What are the $0$-subscripts supposed to mean? Shouldn't $\nabla$ map the other way around (from $1$st order Sobolev space to $L^2$)?

Comment: I think there is something wrong here. Certainly, in order for $\nabla u$ to exist, we need $u \in H^1(\Omega)$ and then having applied the operator, we will have $\nabla u \in L^2(\Omega)$ (meaning that each component of $\nabla u$ is in $L^2(\Omega)$).

Comment: @JanBohr I'm not the OP, but I believe we typically define $L_0^2(\Omega)$ as the closure of $C^\infty_c(\Omega)$ in the $L^2$-norm (or equivalently, the $L^2(\Omega)$ functions with zero trace) and likewise  $H^1_0(\Omega)$ is the closure of $C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ in the $H^1$-norm (or equivalently, the $H^1(\Omega)$ functions with zero trace).

Comment: Sorry ,I have edited the space

Comment: @User8128 The closure of $C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ in the $L^2$-norm is all of $L^2$ in every reasonable scenario.

Comment: @JanBohr You're right - my mistake. I forgot the trace operator is only well-defined on $W^{1,p}$. Not sure what $L^2_0$ is then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all very formal and non-rigorous (essentially, I'm assuming everything is smooth and giving a heuristic explanation), but if we let $\lambda$ be a continuous functional on the image of $\nabla$, then for any $u$ in the image of $\nabla$ (so that $u = \nabla f$ for some $f$), then using integration by parts we see $$\langle u,\lambda\rangle = \int_\Omega u\lambda \, \mathrm{d}x =  \int_\Omega (\nabla f) \lambda \,\mathrm{d}x= - \int_\Omega f (\nabla \cdot \lambda) \, \mathrm{d}x = -\langle f , \nabla \cdot \lambda \rangle$$ where the boundary term is zero because the functions are zero on the boundary. Now if $\lambda, \mu$ are two members of the continuous dual of the image of $\nabla$ such that $\nabla \cdot \lambda = \nabla \cdot \mu$, then we see $$\langle u, \lambda - \mu \rangle = \langle f, \nabla \cdot \mu - \nabla \cdot \lambda \rangle = 0$$ for all $u$ in the image of $\nabla$. But this shows that $\lambda = \mu$ on the image of $\nabla$ and thus any two functions $\lambda, \mu$ with $\nabla \cdot \lambda = \nabla \cdot \mu$ are equal as members of the dual of the image of $\nabla$; however, as members of the dual of the whole space, $\lambda$ and $\mu$ may still be different (i.e., they're only necessarily equal when $u = \nabla f$ for some $f$). Thus to get the dual of the image of $\nabla$, we can take the dual of the whole space, but identify functions whose divergence are equal; this is exactly what it means to quotient the space by $$Z = \{f \, : \, \nabla \cdot f = 0 \}.$$